# Magento nginx ssl redirect loop error

Tags: php, redirect, ssl, nginx, magento-1.7

I have a magento 1.7 installation on nginx server.Whenever i enable SSL for front end from magento admin, the page gives an error:

Error:This webpage has a redirect loop

I have tried the following solution but no sucess:

Url : https://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/magento-kb/magento-https-redirect-loop/

What can be wrong in my Magento settings:

1. Validate session settings are off.
2. SSL cretificate is installed
3. secure and no-secure urls are defined already.

My nginx.conf is

```
user              nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  notice;
#error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  info;

pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
worker_connections  1024; }


 http {
include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;

log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

sendfile        on;
#tcp_nopush     on;

#keepalive_timeout  0;
keepalive_timeout  65;

#gzip  on;

#
# The default server
#
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  _;

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    error_page  404              /404.html;
    location = /404.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }

    # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    #}

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    root           html;
    #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    #    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
    #    include        fastcgi_params;
    #}

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    #location ~ /\.ht {
    #    deny  all;
    #}
}

# Load config files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
```

}

Comment: I think you need to share your nginx config

Comment: sure..please wait a moment

Comment: not seeing anything related to serving https in there, is there some config missing?

Answer (score 0):

We've had a similar issue with Magento. It normally is fixed by clearing your website cookies. So I found this snippet that clears all website cookies for the domain. I placed it at the top of the main store index.php page. It has to be the first thing so it doesn't interfere with regular store SSL and Shopping functions. (e.g  www.mysite.com/store/index.php)

```
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE'])) {
     $cookies = explode(';', $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']);
       foreach($cookies as $cookie) {
         $parts = explode('=', $cookie);
         $name = trim($parts[0]);
        setcookie($name, '', time()-1000);
        setcookie($name, '', time()-1000, '/');
      }
    }
```